# EE 2 and Transcribe - Get related entry ids

Tags: ee2, transcribe

EE 2.9.3
Transcribe 1.6.2

I have an older EE site where I need to output the entry_id of the associated translated entry.

Something like this:

on the English listing page:

```
English title
English Summary
  - French Entry ID
```

And then on the French page this:

```
French Title
French Summary
  - English Entry ID
```

Is this possible? If so how? Maybe through a database query? Not sure how to do that either. FWIW I can't upgrade to the latest EE or transcribe.

Looking in the database I see a table `exp_transcribe_entries_languages` with a column of `relationship_id` that contains a hash which is duplicated on associated entries. other columns are `id`, `language_id`, and `entry_id`

So two entries that are related to each other include:

```
id    language_id   entry_id  relationship_id
1372      1           1372     5bf41ee76f1ef
1376      2           1376     5bf41ee76f1ef
```

You can see the relationship_id matches. Is there a database query that I could put in a template so that I can output the entry id of the opposite language. Where langauge_id of 1 = english and 2 = french

something like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="5" disable="member_data|comments"}
    <h2>{title}</h2>

    <p>Current Language Entry ID: {entry_id}</p>
    <p>Other Language Entry ID: db_query_here</p>

  </article>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you could use this according to the docs:

```
{exp:transcribe:language_links has_entry="yes"}{languages}{rel:entry_id}{/languages}{/exp:transcribe:language_links}
```